# Flexslider load at end, after all ads and scripts

Tags: jquery, wordpress, flexslider

I noticed that my Flexslider load slides after all ads and script finished loading, and on flexslider place is “big hole” until all that scripts and ads finish their load!? Did you know why is that?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).load(function() {
jQuery('#featured').flexslider({
slideshowSpeed: 6000,
directionNav:true,
pauseOnHover:true,
controlNav: false,
manualControls: '.flexslide-custom-controls li a',
controlsContainer: '.container'
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Because you are using `jQuery(window).load(function() {`

Comment: Trying using jQuery(document).ready( instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your following line:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
```

for this one:

```
jQuery(window).ready(function() {
```

so you just create the slider right when the `DOM` is ready, instead of when images and other resources have finished loading.

But make sure Flexslider to work well, does not need any of those resources to be loaded first.

Comment: Thank you m8! looks that is now ok!